# How to automatically resize the grid when the form is resized?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

How to automatically resize grid or another child component when my form is resized?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the grid `Width` property to "Column width" and `Height` to "Column height". Do so for any outer container (group, tab, tab-page and so on).

`StringEdit` and some other controls can do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Change values of width and height to 'column width' and 'column height' respectively.